# Want to use a view but cannot have a foreign key

Tags: database, database-design

Lets say I have the following entities: Customer, Account, Agreement, Sub-agreement, sub-agreement-account.

A customer owns zero or more accounts, a customer has zero or more agreements. Each agreement has all accounts of a certain type(s) that the customer has access to. The customer can have access to more then his own accounts, so I have a view that retrieves all accounts (with account type) that the customer has access to.

Since an agreement has accounts of a certain type I would like a new view to help me with ease querying that would give me all accounts for a certain agreement (basically using the first view but joining it with the account types of the agreement).

The customer may then create sub-agreements using the agreement as a base. So the customer can choose to create a sub-agreement with some subset of the accounts that are on the base agreement (sub-agreement-account). Here I would like an foreign key to the accounts of the base agreement, to prevent an account to be inserted into a sub agreement that isn't in the base agreement. But since that only is a view it's not possible!

Should I skip the foreign key and use application logic (and maybe a foreign key between Account and sub-agreement-account as well) to make certain it isn't possible to insert an account on a sub agreement that isn't on a base agreement? Or should I introduce a table "agreement-account", materializing the view that helped me to get accounts on an agreement and have my application maintain that table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would NEVER create any extra tables to enforce (occasional) relationship constraint.
By all means create natural relationships/constraints between account and agreement, but don't introduce any extra data complexity for the sake of occasional use.
Present the user at the point of creating sub-agreement with the subset of accounts valid for base agreement and double check selected list on save.